# How can I get font like the font of the Mathematics Magazine (MAA)?

Tags: fonts

I like the font Mathematics Magazine very much, but I don't know how to select this font. How can I get font like Mathematics Magazine?

[image]

Comment: I have never heard of this font and Google doesn't give me anything. Please post a link to information about the font.

Comment: I am sorry. I only have the newspaper.

Comment: I think you are talking about the sans serif font. The font is called [Optima](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/optima/).

Comment: A'ha. So it is *not* called "Mathematics Magazine" as claimed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are talking about the sans serif font (the serif font is Times).

This font is called Optima and a clone is available for LaTeX as URW Classico.

You can find informations in the LaTeX font catalogue at the [Optima](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/optima/) page.

If you don't have it installed on your system, go to the corresponding [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/classico/) page, where you will find the package to be downloaded and instructions for installing it on your system.