# Nice output for examination

Tags: fonts, pdftex, tcolorbox, rules, mdframed

We currently have this MWE with classic Palatino font (or with Times NR).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,tikz}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.2cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\starthfill}{\noindent\makebox[0pt]{}\hfill}
\newcommand*{\hfillend}{\hfill\makebox[0pt]{}}
\newcommand*{\riga}{\noindent\starthfill\rule{8cm}{0.7pt}\hfillend\par}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textsc{\textbf{{\large Liceo \\ (sez. ass.)}\\
Prova scritta di Fisica\\
Sezione A}}
\end{center}
\riga
\vskip .3cm
\parindent 0cm
\textit{Durante la prova non è consentito consultare libri, appunti e strumentazione elettronica ad eccezione di una calcolatrice scientifica o standard ma non l'app dello smartphone.}

\vskip .5cm
Lo studentessa risolva a scelta \textbf{solo tre} dei seguenti quattro problemi/quesiti/esercizi.


\vskip 1.5cm
\begin{center}
\textbf{I}
\end{center}
Una carica puntiforme $q =-0.35$ nC è fissata all'origine. Dove deve
un protone affinché la forza elettrica che agisce su di esso sia
esattamente opposta al suo peso? (Che l'asse $y$ sia verticale e l'asse $x$
sia orizzontale).

\vskip 1cm
\begin{center}
\textbf{II}
\end{center}
Supponi che la carica $q_2$ della figura sottostante possa essere spostata a sinistra o a destra lungo la linea che congiunge $q_1$ e $q_3$. Data $q = +12 \mu$C, calcola a quale distanza da $q_1$ la forza a cui è sottoposta $q_2$ si annulla.
\vskip .5cm
\begin{center}

\end{center}

\vskip .5cm
\begin{center}
\textbf{III}
\end{center}

Due cariche puntiformi di eguale valore distano tra di loro 7.5 cm. Nel punto medio della congiungente le due cariche il campo elettrostatico risultante è 45 N/C. Calcola il valore delle cariche e il loro segno.


\end{document}
```

The screenshot is:

[image]

1. I would like to put a background in the head below the title like in this image below

[image]

2. and to realize, for each problem, this style

[image]

where the Example (Problema) should have a font that is a clone of Optima font or Gillius in `pdfLaTeX`.

Comment: This is almost certainly opinion-based…

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple unrelated questions, here. Is question 1 about how to get a gray bar/rectangle below the head or in the background of the head? It is not completely clear to me. Is there a third question about how to get that font in pdfLaTeX? Maybe split this into multiple questions.

Comment: If you want to know how to get 1) a box with gray background and 2) boxes styled with this fancy blue frame using, for example, `tcolorbox`, I would argue that it would be okay to ask both in one question. This is, at least, how I understand your question.

Comment: Here is a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151053/123129) about Optima font. The suggestion there is the [urw/classico](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/urwclassico/) font ([CTAN: /tex-archive/fonts/urw/classico](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/classico/)).

Comment: @dexteritas Kindly you are right but I put it all together so as not to separate my question into so many fragments. I often use the Optima font clone; you can see in my question list that there should be something similar. Maybe in the multiple choice questions if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope I understood everything correctly since you seem to ask multiple things at once, but you could maybe start with this approach:

(Thanks to @dexteritas for his suggestion for improvement!)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.2cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\usepackage{gillius}
\usepackage[letterspace=100]{microtype}

\newcommand*{\starthfill}{\noindent\makebox[0pt]{}\hfill}
\newcommand*{\hfillend}{\hfill\makebox[0pt]{}}
\newcommand*{\riga}{\noindent\starthfill\rule{8cm}{0.7pt}\hfillend\par}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcounter{problema}
\newtcolorbox{problema}[2][]{
    empty,
    boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, right=10pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    coltitle=black,
    title={%
        \sffamily\large%
        \textbf{\color{cyan}\lsstyle\MakeUppercase{Problema}\ifstrempty{#1}{}{~#1}:}%
        \tikzmark{titlemark \theproblema}\quad#2%
    },
    before title={\stepcounter{problema}},
    after upper={\tikzmark{endmark \theproblema}},
    remember,
    overlay={
        \begin{scope}[remember picture, overlay, cyan, line width=1pt]
            \draw ([yshift=5pt]frame.north west) -- 
                ([yshift=5pt]frame.north east) |-
                ([xshift=5pt]pic cs:endmark \theproblema);
            \draw[fill=cyan] ([xshift=5pt]pic cs:endmark \theproblema) rectangle
                ++(5pt,5pt);
            \draw[fill=cyan] ([yshift=5pt]frame.north west) rectangle
                ++({pic cs:titlemark \theproblema} |- 3pt,3pt);
        \end{scope}
    },
}

\newtcolorbox{introduzione}{
    tile,
    colbacklower=lightgray,
}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textsc{\textbf{{\large Liceo \\ (sez. ass.)} \\
Prova scritta di Fisica \\
Sezione A}}
\end{center}

\riga

\begin{introduzione}
\textit{Durante la prova non è consentito consultare libri, appunti e strumentazione elettronica ad eccezione di una calcolatrice scientifica o standard ma non l'app dello smartphone.}

\vskip .5cm
Lo studentessa risolva a scelta \textbf{solo tre} dei seguenti quattro problemi/quesiti/esercizi.
\end{introduzione}

\vskip 1cm
\begin{problema}[I]{Il primo problema}
Una carica puntiforme $q =-0.35$ nC è fissata all'origine. Dove deve
un protone affinché la forza elettrica che agisce su di esso sia
esattamente opposta al suo peso? (Che l'asse $y$ sia verticale e l'asse $x$
sia orizzontale).
\end{problema}

\vskip 1cm
\begin{problema}[II]{Il secondo problema}
Supponi che la carica $q_2$ della figura sottostante possa essere spostata a sinistra o a destra lungo la linea che congiunge $q_1$ e $q_3$. Data $q = +12 \mu$C, calcola a quale distanza da $q_1$ la forza a cui è sottoposta $q_2$ si annulla.
\end{problema}

\vskip 1cm
\begin{problema}[III]{Il terzo problema}
Due cariche puntiformi di eguale valore distano tra di loro 7.5 cm. Nel punto medio della congiungente le due cariche il campo elettrostatico risultante è 45 N/C. Calcola il valore delle cariche e il loro segno.
\end{problema}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 nice. The line `\draw[fill=cyan] ([xshift=5pt]pic cs:endmark \theproblema) |- ++(5pt,5pt) -- ++(0,-5pt) -- cycle;` could be shortened to `\draw[fill=cyan] ([xshift=5pt]pic cs:endmark \theproblema) rectangle ++(5pt,5pt);` (also the following line).

Comment: Oh, you are right ... It seems that I was a bit tired when coding this ...

Comment: For me, not only is it perfect. It's exceptional. Thank you so much. I would also like to thank to @dexteritas :-)